# Google Sheets - tricks with Ranges in ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

For example you have `A1 = {1;2;3}`

So, if you want to make cumulative sum in `B1` you make this:

```
B1 = ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(A1:A3);"<="&row(A1:A3);A1:A3))
```

Or more flexible variant:

```
B1 =ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A:A));"<="&INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A:A);INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(R:R)))))
```

This variant expands according to length of Array in `A1` and does not grow to the end of the sheet.

I want to use value of `A1` directly in formula like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(sumif(row({1;2;3});"<="&row({1;2;3}));{1;2;3})
```

But it will not accept `{}`, because it requires range, but not array.

Does anyone have a trick to override this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

```
=ArrayFormula(sumif({1;2;3},"<="&{1;2;3}))
```

## Explanation

The sintax of SUMIF is `SUMIF(range, criterion, [sum_range])`

sum_range is an optional parameter to be used when it's different from range. As sum_range and range are the same then *the trick* is not to use sum_range.

## Reference

[SUMIF - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en)